# React native video : fullscreen on iOS breaks layout when exit

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fullscreen, react-native-video

## Step to reproduce

Start a fresh react-native project

With this package.json

```
    {
      "name": "verifCamera4",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.8.3",
        "react-native": "0.59.8",
        "react-native-video": "git+https://github.com/nfb-onf/react-native-video.git#master"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
        "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```

Then using this snippet you'll be able to reproduce the error :

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Video from "react-native-video";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>

          <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: "row"}}>
            <Video controls
                   source={{uri: "https://app.dollycast.io/films/102/maestro_product-1551264704/movie_maestro_product-1551264704_1.mp4"}}
                   style={{borderWidth: 1, width:300, height: 300}}/>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

In order to reproduce this you have to :

- Launch the app.
- When the app Screen is loaded launch the video
- Then go fullscreen
- Rotate your device to go landscape or portrait
- close the fullscreen
- Now there is an issue, layout is broken.

A video component inside a ScrollView seems to break the layout.

This issue has been reported twice on the maintainer repo but even if contributors have answered they were unable to resolve this in months.

I've made a video today about a weird way to make the bug away, until the next fullscreen. There is also a demonstration of the bug : 
https://youtu.be/tYxY1WJkuO8

If you want to know more about this bug you can go to the two issues reported with all participations from contributors [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1319) and [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1645)

From a contributor this bug is related to the onLayout see below:

> Normally onLayout is called when a view has a flex=1. This continues
>   to work with Views and fullscreen, however, when a ScrollView is
>   involved, exiting Fullscreen stops the flex=1 from triggering an
>   onLayout change, which results in the layout being incorrect. It seems
>   to be a rendering issue deeper in the React code;

Why I'm here then ? Because I can't get this to work myself and I'm looking for a workaround or an expert that have experienced this and found a way to make it work. Maybe contribute to this awesome package also.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Video link you shared is not available anymore, I checked the thread in issues but I didn't get the solution